# Binding DataContext in XAML With DataContext Set In Code

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have the following code:

**ProcessMainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
public ProcessMainWindow(SourceTableRowInfo rowContent)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = rowContent;
    }
```

**ProcessMainWindow.xaml**

```
  <!--Insert Code---->
  <TabItem x:Name="postProcessTab" Header="Post-Processes">
            <local:PostProcessUserControl PostProcessItem="{Binding PostProcess, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
        </TabItem>
```

So RowContent has an element called PostProcess in it. I am trying to bind that element to a UserControl Dependency Property, but cannot get the binding to work. Based off what I was reading [here (Using the DataContext)](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/data-binding/using-the-datacontext/) my understanding is that what I have should work, but I can't get it to work. So am I misunderstanding what it is saying? I have read a few other pages but still can't figure it out.

I have also tried:

```
<!--Insert Code---->
  <TabItem x:Name="postProcessTab" Header="Post-Processes">
            <local:PostProcessUserControl PostProcessItem="{Binding, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Path=PreProcess}" />
        </TabItem>
```

If these are correct, I guess I have an error elsewhere in my code. I have yet to fully understand data binding in WPF to know if that is the case though so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: That should work, but it's worth pointing out that the XAML designer isn't going to use that constructor.

Comment: "RowContent has an element called PostProcess": Does that mean that `SourceTableRowInfo` has a public property, with a public `get`, named `PostProcess`?

Comment: @EdPlunkett Yes, that is correct.

Comment: One thing to try is to put a trace on the BInding: `PostProcessItem="{Binding PostProcess, PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High}`. Then look for what it tells you at runtime in the Output pane in VS. Very handy. Did you write `PostProcessUserControl` yourself? If so, did you try putting a changed event handler on `PostProcessItem` with a breakpoint in it?

Comment: @EdPlunkett Dang....well I feel really really stupid now. I had never even thought to check the Output of the code and sure enough it told me that PostProcess didn't exist in SourceTableRowInfo, it should be Postprocess...and it works like a charm now

Comment: @EdPlunkett If you answer saying check your output and make sure things are named correctly, I will give you the answer since that was the fix and that's what you suggested.

Comment: Sure, may as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing to try is to put a trace on the Binding:

```
PostProcessItem="{Binding PostProcess, PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High}.
```

Then look for what it tells you at runtime in the Output pane in VS. This can help you identify cases where your `DataContext` isn't what you think it is, or your `Path` is misspelled -- all the simple stuff that the compiler catches in C# but can't be detected at compile time in a late-binding/duck-typed miasma like XAML.

Don't leave those traces on bindings once you're done with them; they can really slow things down. Or at least set `TraceLevel=None`, to save trouble if think you'll be coming back to one later.

Comment: Additional question that you may know the answer to, Postprocess is of type PostProcess (elements are Name, Description), if I want to bind to those specific elements, would it just be {Binding Postprocess.Name ....}?

Comment: @K.Fenster Yes. The default constructor parameter for Binding is Path, which means just what it sounds like -- so that's implicitly `{Binding Path=Postprocess.Name}`